# NUnit Collection Assert That item in list is after/before another item

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

I would like to do something along the lines of...

```
Assert.That(collection, Has.Item("two").After.Item("one"))
```

Is this possible with NUnit?

Comment: You can write that if you want, sure. [Start with this doc](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/extending-nunit/Custom-Constraints.html), and if you get stuck on a specific point, feel free to ask for further help.

Comment: I guess this reads pretty well, still would wonder if there is an official way that would provide a better failure message:

`Assert.That(collection.IndexOf("two"), Is.GreaterThan(collection.IndexOf("one"))`

Comment: [Here's a list of all constraints](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/Constraints.html), and I don't see one which matches your spec exactly. Don't forget that you can specify your own failure messages

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of [this page](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/Constraints.html), I'm out of luck this time (thanks @canton7). A suggestion was made to make a custom constraint, which I find fascinating, but probably an overkill for this scenario.

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
Assert.That(collection.IndexOf("two"), Is.GreaterThan(collection.IndexOf("one")))
```